# How to handle a model with many attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord backed model with just over 60 attributes. In the controller, passing such a large field list to strong parameters looks like a code smell.

Is there any downside to trying to split the attributes out into several related ActiveRecord backed models and having the main model reach each of them via has_one relationships?

Comment: I'd love to see what kind of attributes you are storing. Maybe some of them could be managed better...

Comment: Maybe its time to break off the model? Seems like 60 attributes for a single model is pretty large. Is it storing a lot of data that may fit a different model better?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need all 60 attributes than keeping them in one table/model is the best way to go. Don't bother about the long strong parameters part at the bottom of your controller.